# Hi, I wrote code in C++ fot linear search but it displays the index of searched elemet twice with second index value as random garbage value

Tags: search, stack

Here is the code.what i did is implement linear search on some elements of the array and the push searched elements in stack,afterwards I print the popped elements from stack and print them.But in search function it displays two index values.

````
using namespace std;

int searched[10];
int stack[100], n=100, top=-1;
void push(int val) {
   if(top>=n-1)
   cout<<"Stack Overflow"<<endl;
   else {
      top++;
      stack[top]=val;
   }
}
void pop() {
   if(top<=-1)
   cout<<"Stack Underflow"<<endl;
   else {
      cout<<"The popped element is "<< stack[top] <<endl;
      top--;
   }
}
void display() {
   if(top>=0) {
      cout<<"Stack elements are:";
      for(int i=top; i>=0; i--)
      cout<<stack[i]<<" ";
      cout<<endl;
   } else
   cout<<"Stack is empty";
}

int search(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] == x)
        cout<<"The element is found at the index"<<i<<"\n\n";
            return x;
            

}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[15] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    int x = 0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
    x++;
    int result = search(arr, n, x);
        cout << "searched Element is " << result<<"\t\t";
        
        push(result);
        pop();
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that lead to this confusing result.

First, if I am not mistaken the search function, which was written like this:

```cpp
int search(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] == x)
        cout<<"The element is found at the index"<<i<<"\n\n";
            return x;
            

}
```

is parsed similarly to the following:

```cpp
int search(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == x) {
            cout<<"The element is found at the index"<<i<<"\n\n";
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Presumably you meant this:

```cpp
int search(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == x) {
            cout<<"The element is found at the index"<<i<<"\n\n";
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Second, since the global `n` starts at the value `100`, the `search` loop runs off the end of the length 15 array, into other memory. This is probably undefined behavior.